# Protractor e2e test case for downloading csv file without prompt

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Protractor `e2e` test case for downloading `csv` file without prompt is not working with the following code. Please help me on this. I have gone through all the stuff already available in stackoverflow. Nothing worked for me...

```
var q = require("q");
var FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");

var makeFirefoxProfile = function(preferenceMap, specs) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    for (var key in preferenceMap) {
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
    }


    firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = {
            browserName: "firefox",
            acceptInsecureCerts: true,
            "moz:webdriverClick": false,
            firefox_profile: encodedProfile,
        };

        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};


exports.config = {
  getMultiCapabilities: function() {
        return q.all([
            makeFirefoxProfile(
                {
                    "browser.download.dir": "./",
                    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "text/commaseparated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext"
            },
        )
    ]);
},



  // NOTE: this will need changing if a new version of selenium
  // standalone server is released --->
  seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar',

  specs: [
    'test/e2e/app.e2e_spec.js',
    'test/e2e/**/*.e2e_spec.js',
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    firefox_profile: makeFirefoxProfile,
    "moz:webdriverClick": false
  },


  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 240000
  },

  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3030/',

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  framework: 'jasmine'
};
```

With the above is my `protractor.conf` file not working, Prompt pop-up is coming for file download.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.